# how can i take the user input to complete my system() function in c++

Tags: c++, gcc

i want to take the user input and use it to complete the function below in system ()

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{

    int bssid;
    int chanel;
    cout<<"Enter the targets Bssid = "<<endl;
    cin>>bssid;
    cout<<"Enter the channel"<<endl;
    cin>>chanel;

    system("airodump-ng --bssid" + bssid  " -c " + channel + " wlan0mon");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` combined with `std::to_string()` provides you an easy opportunity to format strings.

```
std::string Input = "hackwifi " + std::to_string(bssid) + " --emacsoversendmail " + std::to_string(channel);
```

Then, to get a null-terminated c-string call `std::string::c_str()`

```
system(Input.c_str());
```

**Note**: this method is supported in C++11 and above

Comment: Please, more answer. Need to " and escape strings.